# SQL select column with conditions JAVA

Tags: java, sql, select

I tried to get specific value where the column of names in my database contains "jansen",but when i run my code it shows error like this

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'jansen' in 'where clause'
```

here is my code

```
try {
     Statement stmt=MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp where name = jansen");
     while(rs.next())
         System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2)+" "+rs.getString(3));
     }catch (Exception e){
          System.out.println(e);
    }
```

[and here is my database in Sqlyog]

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put quotes around string values in your SQL statement.

```
"select * from emp where name = 'jansen'"
```

Another issue you may run into later, is that your resources (e.g. connection, statement, ...) aren't cleaned up after you've used them. You should actually call the `close()` function after using it. You would then have to put that code inside a `finally` block, and again catch it to prevent having the `close` function itself throwing exceptions. Because it would be messy and bloated, there's a better solution to clean things up:

Create your statement between the braces of your `try`, and it will close it cleanly for you. (It's called a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement)

```
try (Statement stmt = MyConnection.getConnection().createStatement()) {
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
  while (rs.next()) {
    ...
  }
} catch (SQLException e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

You can read more about executing SQL statements in java, in [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html).

Comment: can we select * from using preparedstatement instead of using statement?

Comment: @JansenStanlie you could and if the value `"Jansen"` is provided by a user you definitely should. However, if the value `"Jansen"` isn't dynamic then there's nothing wrong with hardcoding it in the query.

Comment: PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from emp");  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();  
while(rs.next()){  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getString(2));  
}  
like this sir?

Comment: If you want to use prepared statements, take a look at the answer of @rortegat below. What he does looks correct. Also, you may want to use the column names to extract the results, I wouldn't put much faith in the indices of the table columns. (e.g. `rs.getInt(1)` makes your code unreadable and unpredictable)

Comment: Thnkyou so much for the explanation

Comment: @JansenStanlie e.g. `rs.getInt("ID")`, `rs.getString("Name")`, `rs.getString("Age")`

Comment: is there a way for us to delete duplicate name in the table by using java?

Comment: @JansenStanlie it would make sense to add "a unique key constraint" on the database table column. Then your database will throw errors when you try to add them. - If you want to remove records from a database using java, you could make a prepared statement with an SQL query like `"delete from emp where id = ?"` and then call `.execute()`. - An illustrated example of a delete: https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-delete-query-example/

Comment: for condition like IDs i'm using Pk and Auto increment where the database will throw error when i inserted the same ID into database, but using an unique constraint for column name and address i have no Idea about that

Comment: @JansenStanlie in MySQL, you could execute the following SQL statement:  `ALTER TABLE emp ADD CONSTRAINT uniqueEmp1 UNIQUE (name)`  You can just run this in SQLyog. However, you first need to get rid of the duplicate record. MySQL wouldn't let you add a constraint if the constraint is already violated beforehand.

Comment: okat it seems i have found the answer, by using if handler and UNIQUE in my SQLyog, thankyou again sir

Answer (score 1):

You should use a PreparedStatement instead of Statement in this way:

```java
PreparedStatement statement = MyConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("select * from emp where name = :empId");
statement.setString(empId, "jansen");
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Then "jansen" would be replaced by String variable with dynamic name.

Comment: can we use more than one condition ? such as if i want the specific name and the specific Age

Comment: @JansenStanlie you may also want to take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html which holds the official documentation regarding prepared statements.

Comment: thankyou both you and @bvdb helps me a lot